# Theorem of Lebesgue and differentiation of a parameter integral

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

> > Let $(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an interval and let $\left\{f_t\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\right\}_{t\in (a,b)}$ be a family of measurable functions on the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, which are differentiable in $t_0\in (a,b)$ almost surely and for which there exists a $g\in\mathfrak{L}_{\mu}^1$ with $\lvert f_t-f_{t_0}\rvert\leq g\lvert t-t_0\rvert$ almost surely for all t in a neighboorhood $U$ of $t_0$. Show that for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$ it is
> >     $$
> > \left. \frac{d}{dt}\int_A f_t\, d\mu\right|_{t=t_0}=\int_A\left. \frac{d}{dt} f_t\right|_{t=t_0}\, d\mu.
> > $$

Good evening!

Here is my proof, would you please say me if it is okay or if there are mistakes?

**Proof**

Consider any $A\in\mathcal{A}$.
Without loss of generality consider a sequence $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset U\cap (a,b)$ with $t_n\to t_0$ and $t_n\neq t_0\forall~n\in\mathbb{N}$. Define
$$
f_n:=\frac{f_{t_n}-f_{t_0}}{t_n-t_0},~~M_n:=\left\{f_{t_n}\text{ not differentiable in }t_0\right\},~~M:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n.
$$
It is $\mu(M_n)=\mu(M)=0$.

Moreover define
$$
g_n:=1_{A\setminus M}f_n, n\geq 1.
$$
$g_n$ is measurable, because $f_n$ and $1_{A\setminus M}$ are measurable. Additionally, it is pointwise
$$
g_n\to 1_{A\setminus M}\left. \frac{d}{dt}f_t\right|_{t=t_0}
$$
and $1_{A\setminus M}\left. \frac{d}{dt}f_t\right|_{t=t_0}$ is measurable, because $g_n$ is measurable and the pointwise limit exists.

*(By the way: This is the reason why I defined $g_n$ and did not use $f_n$, because $f_n\to\left. \frac{d}{dt}f_t\right|_{t=t_0}$ almost surely (what would be okay for the Theorem of Lebesgue), but the limit of $f_n$ exists only almost surely and  so $\left. \frac{d}{dt}f_t\right|_{t=t_0}$ is not measurable - but this is needed to apply Lebesgue.)*

So all is given to use Lebesgue's Theorem.

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A g_n\, d\mu=\int_A1_{A\setminus M}\left. \frac{d}{dt}f_t\right|_{t=t_0}\, d\mu.
$$

Now, because of 
$$
g_n=f_n\text{ almost surely },~~1_{A\setminus M}\left. \frac{d}{dt}f_t\right|_{t=t_0}=\left. \frac{d}{dt} f_t\right|_{t=t_0}\text{ almost surely},
$$
it is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A f_n\, d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A g_n\, d\mu=\int_A1_{A\setminus M}\left. \frac{d}{dt}f_t\right|_{t=t_0}\, d\mu=\int_A\left. \frac{d}{dt}f_t\right|_{t=t_0}\, d\mu.
$$
And because of the linearity of the Lebesgue-integral it is finally
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A f_n\, d\mu=\left. \frac{d}{dt}\int_A f_t\, d\mu\right|_{t=t_0}.
$$

---

Please say me if my proof is allright. Would be very kind!

Sinccerely yours,

math12

Comment: The task is as given above. I just cited it. I think it is meant $f\colon (a,b)\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R},(t,\omega)\mapsto f(t,\omega)$, isn't it? Instead of writing it this way, it is written as $f_t\colon \Omega\to\mathbb{R},\omega\mapsto (t,\omega)$ I guess.

Comment: Or what is your objection?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I misunderstood your notation.