# Parameter integral and continuity (Theorem of Lebesgue)

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

I already kept myself busy with a proof concerning the [Theorem of Lebesgue and differentiation of a parameter integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586946/theorem-of-lebesgue-and-differentiation-of-a-parameter-integral). Unfortunately I did not get an answer there yet.

Now my task is nearly the same - but this time dealing with continuity.

> > Consider the measruable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$. Let $\left\{f_t\colon\Omega\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}\right\}_{t\in B}$ be a family of measruable function, induced by a subset $B\subset E$ of a metric space $E$, so that for a $g\in\mathfrak{L}_{\mu}^1$ it is $\sup\limits_{t\in B}\lvert f_t\rvert\leq g$ almost surely. Moreover assume that the function $t\mapsto f_{t}(\omega)$ is continious in $t_0\in B$ for $\omega\in\Omega$ almost surely. Show, that $t\mapsto\varphi(t):=\int_A f_t\, d\mu, B\to\mathbb{R},$ is continious in $t_0$ for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$.

**Proof**

Consider any $A\in\mathcal{A}$.

Let $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $B$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=t_0$.

Set 
$$
f_n:=f_{t_{n}}, n\in\mathbb{N},~~~~~M_n:=\left\{f_{t_n}\mbox{ is not continious in }t_0\right\}, n\in\mathbb{N},~~~~~M:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n.
$$

$M_n, n\in\mathbb{N},$ and $M$ are zero sets, i.e.
$$
\mu(M_n)=\mu(M)=0.
$$

My intention is to apply the Theorem of Lebesgue.

It is $f_{t_n}\to f_{t_0}$ alomost surely. That would be fine in order to apply Lebesgue.

However, in order to apply Lebesgue, it is furthermore necessary that $f_{t_0}$ is measurable. Because the $f_n$ are measurable this would be the case if the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{t_n}(\omega)$ would exist pointwise. But this is not the case here, because the limit only exists almost surely!

In order to solve this problem I decided to consider

$g_n:=1_{A\setminus M}f_{t_n}$,

because the $g_n$ are measurable and hence here the pointwise limit exists and is $1_{A\setminus M}f_{t_0}$, so this time the limit is indeed measurable.

Because of
$$
\lvert g_n\rvert\leq\lvert f_n\rvert\leq\sup_{t\in B}\lvert f_t\rvert\leq g\text{ almost surely}
$$

I now can apply the Theorem of Lebesgue, getting
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A g_n\, d\mu=\int_A 1_{A\setminus M}f_{t_0}\, d\mu
$$

and because of $g_n=f_n$ almost surely and $1_{A\setminus M}f_{t_0}=f_{t_0}$ almost surely, it is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A f_{t_n}\, d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A g_n\, d\, d\mu=\int_A 1_{A\setminus M}f_{t_0}\, d\mu=\int_A f_{t_0}\, d\mu.
$$

And that was to show. $\diamond$

---

Please tell me, if my proof is allright. I am really excited to know if my efforts are right!

Sincerely yours,

math12

Comment: 12 your proof looks similar to the normal case where is "almost surely" not mentioned however im not an expert but you can find the normal case here on pages 88-89   http://books.google.ch/books?id=5mskCf1wKPkC&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&focus=viewport&hl=de&output=html_text

Comment: Yes, indeed looks similar. But the question is still, if my adoption to the "almost everywhere" case is fine or not. :-)

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand why nobody answers me. ;(