# Expectated value of a time-derivative of time-dependent random variable with time-dependent probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value

I am new to stochastic process and I have a trouble to show
\begin{equation}
E\left[\frac{df(V)}{dt} \right] = \frac{d}{dt} E\left[f(V) \right],
\end{equation}
where $V = V(t)$ is the time-dependent random variable and the probability (density) to obatain $V(t) = v$ is given by
\begin{align*}
P(t, v) \equiv P(V(t) = v).
\end{align*}

Then I was taught when $V$ satisfies
\begin{align*}
\frac{dV}{dt} = - a (V),
\end{align*}
we can derive $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} P(t, v) = \frac{\partial}{\partial v} a (v) P (t, v)$.

To derive the equation, we need to use the first relation $E\left[\frac{df(V)}{dt} \right] = \frac{d}{dt} E\left[f(V) \right]$.

With the notation introduced, the first equation becomes

\begin{align*}
E\left[ \frac{dV}{dt} \right] = \int dv f(v) \frac{\partial}{\partial t} P(t, v). 
\end{align*}

However, indeed I do not understand even the definition of the expectated value.

I was taught that is
\begin{align*}
E[g(V)] = \int dv  g(v) P(t, v),
\end{align*}
but I guess here, the realized value $v$ is assume to be independent of time.

Then how can we define the expectated value of $\frac{df}{dt}$? If $v$ in the integral can depend on time, we reach
\begin{align*}
E\left[\frac{df(V)}{dt} \right]  = \int dv(t) \frac{df(v(t))}{dt} P(t, v),
\end{align*}
but I cannot derive the first equation from here.

Although I read some related posts, but I cannot find articles that mention the time-dependence of the probability.

Comment: The statement is not specifically related to stochastic calculus, it is a general result of integrals. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586946/theorem-of-lebesgue-and-differentiation-of-a-parameter-integral), or [here](https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/frey/cours/UdC/ma691/ma691_ann2.pdf) (page 115)

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you for the reply, but maybe I am confused. What is the definition of time-dependent random variables? I guess it is $\int dv f(v) P(t, v)$, but $v$ in $f(v)$ is assumed to be fixed?

Comment: a random variable is just a measurable function. If it depends on time then we have $\operatorname{E}[V_t]=\int_{\Omega }V_t \,d P$, that can also me written as $\operatorname{E}[V(\cdot ,t)]=\int_{\Omega }V(\omega ,t)P(d\omega )$. The notation can change, but for standard notation besides probability theory, we have an integral of the form $\int f(x,y)\mu(dx)$ for some measure $\mu$ that we want to differentiate respect to $y$, if possible. Now check the links given before to see when the identity $\int \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)\mu(dx)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int f(x,y)\mu(dx)$

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you very much. Although it is true that $\frac{d}{dt} \int_x dx f(t, x) = \int_{x} dx \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t, x)$, but for the case the integrand is $ \frac{dv}{dt} P(t, v)$. What I would like to emphasize is both of $\frac{dv}{dt}$ and $P(t, v)$ are time-dependent.

Comment: oh... this is a very different situation when $v$ depends on $t$. In this case the differentiation is a non-linear operator, called a Nemytskii operator. You can read about that in the book *Analysis II* of Herbert Amann and Joachim Escher. The theory about that is far from trivial. Are you sure is that case? Also theory about that (but from a more elementary point of view) can be found in anything that talks about variational calculus

Comment: @Masacroso Actually I still do not understand whether it is the case for now... I am checking it, if the above situation corresponds to that I will answer later! However, the .pdf file which I'm reading says it is the simplest Markov process so it is still possible that some further implicit assumptions are there. Is the $P(t, v)$ is assumed to be time-dependent in simple Markov processes? I am wondering if it means $P(t_0, v)$ for some fixed $t_0$, but then I cannot clarify why the time-derivative of $P(t, v)$ (I wrote it in the question) appears.

Comment: I dont know that, I mean, I'm not familiarized with the theory of continuous time Markov chains